# Bootable ISO from working hard drive

Tags: boot, virtualbox, iso-image

I am looking for a way to create a bootable ISO image of an existing, working hard drive containing a master boot record.

Is there a known solution to this problem?

**Background:**

I have some critical scientific equipment that is running Windows XP. It is increasingly difficult to support compatible hardware. I would like to see if it can run in a virtual machine (e.g.: VirtualBox) on a more modern computer. To try this I need an iso of the existing drive.

**Attempts so far**

- Clonezilla lets me make images, and supposedly even make a 'recovery iso' but this does not appear to be a bootable iso of the actual drive.
- Acronis's software lets me make the bootable media and back up the drive from it, but only to some proprietary format. I don't know how I could get it working with VirtualBox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use instead the Virtual Box Physical to Virtual converter using Disk2VHD.

[VBOX P to V](https://www.wintips.org/how-to-convert-physical-machine-to-virtualbox-machine/)

To convert a physical disk to virtual disk with Disk2vhd:

```
1. Download and extract the Disk2vhd.zip file on the computer that you want to convert to a VirtualBox machine, or on another computer where you have attached the disk of the physical machine that you want to convert to virtual.

2. From the extracted folder, right-click on disk2vhd64.exe and select Run as administrator. Then ask yes at UAC warning.
```

3. At Disk2vhd window:

   Uncheck the Use Vhdx checkbox. *
   Select the physical disk that you want to convert to virtual disk. (In this example I have connected the disk I want to convert to virtual to another pc).
   Select a destination folder and type a name for the created virtual disk file (e.g. "WindowsXP.vhd"). **
   Finally, click Create to create the virtual disk image from the physical disk.